# Wrong page count due to floating objects

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, page-numbering

I've added an appendix to my document and I'm displaying it in the TOC with

```
\clearpage
\pagebreak
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}
```

. The appendix contains 2 pages, each filled with a figure.

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=\textwidth, angle=90]{images/foo}
  \caption{foo}\label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}
\newpage
```

Unfortunately the TOC does not show the correct page number for the appendix. It takes the number of the last page in the document.
For testing reasons I added a line of text, which gave me 3 sides of appendix and then the correct page number was inserted to the TOC. So I think, that there is an issue with the floating objects. 
How do I get this working without adding useless text?

Comment: There would be no room for a figure of height `\textheight` *and* `\caption` to fit within the text block height.

Comment: Even if the figure is smaller, it doesn't work.

Comment: Well then, show us something we can work with. Don't use `images/foo`, but `example-image` (from [`mwe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe)) instead, and provide us with a document (a [MWE](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)) that replicates the results. Pretty please?

Comment: Why aren't you using `\section{Appendix}`? or, even, `\section*{Appendix}` with the manual addition to the contents?

Comment: @cfr Thanks for this advice, works perfectly!

Comment: @cfr I didn't even understand the question, but you have seem to hit the nail on the head. Do you want to add an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B Not much of an answer ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
\section{Appendix}
```

or, for an unnumbered version,

```
\section*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}
```